# JWT Restify exclude Path and all Subpaths

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, jwt, restify

At the moment i use the Node Module jwtRestify for authentication. And i have one problem, i would like exclude some paths from the authentication which is no problem with:

```
server.use(jwtRestify({
secret: config.secret,
requestProperty: 'decoded'}).unless({
  path: [
    baseUrl + '/login',
    baseUrl + '/admin/users',
    baseUrl + '/admin/users/:id',
  ]}))
```

But the /admin/users/:id dont work at all is there a way to exclude all admin routes with something like an regex?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but i found a solution. Underneath restify is using express unless and you can simply use a regex like in the following:

```
server.use(jwtRestify({
secret: config.secret,
requestProperty: 'decoded'}).unless({
  path: [
    baseUrl + '/login',
    baseUrl + '/admin/users',
    /^\/api\/v0\/admin\/users\/.*/,
  ]}))
```